# What is the difference between -> and ->> in PostgreSQL JSON functions?

Tags: json, postgresql, operators, sqldatatypes

The PostgreSQL documentation for [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html) lists both both -> and ->>.

However, it's not clear to me what the difference is between them.

Can anyone provide an explanation with more examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first returns json and the second text:

```
select
    '[1,2,3]'::json->2 as "->",
    pg_typeof('[1,2,3]'::json->2) as "-> type",
    '[1,2,3]'::json->>2 as "-->",
    pg_typeof('[1,2,3]'::json->>2) as "--> type"
;
 -> | -> type | --> | --> type 
----+---------+-----+----------
 3  | json    | 3   | text
```